# Do we get object immutability automatically when using ngrx or ngxs?

Tags: javascript, angular, immutability, immutable.js

Do we automatically get object immutability for all domain instances when using [NGRX](https://github.com/ngrx) or [NGXS](https://github.com/ngxs/store)?  Most of the contexts that I read up on seem to indicate this, but there's also wording like"When we use NGRX with immutable objects ...", so just want to double check that we are not suppose to use something like [`immutable.js`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) in addition to ngrx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NGXS does use immutable objects when working on development mode. Please refer to [state-operations.ts](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/9a736a77e7b68da93a7c3fd50403bc0364f22612/packages/store/src/internal/state-operations.ts) file in ngxs/store repo to verify this.

Start in line 36 and follow the code:

```
if (this._config.developmentMode) {
  return this.ensureStateAndActionsAreImmutable(rootStateOperations);
}
```

In `ensureStateAndActionsAreImmutable` there is `deepFreeze()` which does an `Object.freeze(value)` on values.

So no need for immutable, immer or any immutable library when using ngxs.

If you go with NGRX, you might want to use [ngrx-store-freeze](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/ngrx-store-freeze) instead of third party libs. This has one dependency([deep-freeze-strict](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-freeze-strict)) that will ensure immutability.

Answer (score 4):

No, we don't. If you don't use immutable library, passed payloads must be deeply cloned manually inside reducer (NGRX) or action handler (NGXS) before added to the state.